# how to determine that my model pass all data annotations rule check or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I have scenario where I want to know is my model is valid or not.

here is my model

```
public class CallPartyModel
{
    public System.Guid PartyId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid FwCallMasterId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Principal Party is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Principal Party")]
    public System.Guid PrincipalPartyId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Responsible Party is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Responsible Party")]
    public System.Guid ResponsiblePartyId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "File Type")]
    public System.Guid FileTypeId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Agent Type")]
    public Nullable<System.Guid> AgentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AgentTypeCode { get; set; }
    public bool AdvancedRequired { get; set; }
    public bool SeperateDARequired { get; set; }

    public string PrincipalPartyName { get; set; }
    public string ResponsiblePartyName { get; set; }
    public string PrincipalReferenceCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponsibleReferenceCode { get; set; }
    public string FileTypeName { get; set; }
    public string FileTypeCode { get; set; }

    public string AgentTypeName { get; set; }

    public bool? DAIssuedFlag { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 999999999.999, ErrorMessage = "Value lies outside the 0 to 999999999.999 range")]
    public decimal? AdvanceReceivedAmount { get; set; }

    public System.Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> DeletedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeletedDateTime { get; set; }
    //public virtual UserModel FwCore_Users { get; set; } //Created By User
    //public virtual UserModel FwCore_Users1 { get; set; }//Modified By User
    //public virtual UserModel FwCore_Users2 { get; set; }// Deleted by User

    public bool IsDirtyCheck { get; set; }
    public bool LockPrinFlag { get; set; }
    public string LockPrinMsg { get; set; }
}
```

I have defined some rules for this ex.  `public decimal? AdvanceReceivedAmount { get; set; }`
the range rule.
I know how to check model state when our model is bonded to view as `ModelState.Isvalid()`
but in my code I am working with tow diffident models, its in some wcf service, where I am getting the input as string for all properties and I can't define the data annotation rule on second model. So I have to transfer the data manually from model one to model two and in model two (CallPartyModel) I have define the data annotation rules. Now before performing any transaction in database, I have to check if the model properties's value are valid or not, I know I can do it manually but is there any method as `modelState.IsValid()` for this kind of scenario?

```
as: 
CallPartyModel obj=new CallPartyModel();
obj.AdvanceReceivedAmount=88.88;
if(obj.IsValid())
{
//go
}
else
{
//Show the error according to property
}
```

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150375/check-if-model-is-valid-outside-of-controller)?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Jabiyev yes but I didn't understand from where the ValidationContext came from ? do i have to add any dll reference for it?

Answer (score 1):

How about you check your model1 against model2 by loading the model2 with the values of Model1 and then using

```
 Model2 m2 = new Model2();
 //... load up the values into m2 from Model1

 if(TryUpdateModel(m2))  //if it is ok (checks validation)
 {
    ... your code...
 }
```

I hope this helps.